# AVL Tree Inner Nodes

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, balanced-search-trees, binary-search-trees

If k is the height of an AVL Tree, the minimal number of inner nodes is:
N(k) = N(k-1) + N(k-2) +1.

Why is this formula true?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: proof by induction.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!